# Wordpress plugin Data, Pull Last Element

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

```
global $wpdp;
            $dp = $wpdp->prefix."test-enes";
            $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT `ingredients` FROM $dp WHERE id = (select max(id) from $dp)");
            print_r ($result);

Output is: Array ( )
```

And I used this code:

```
            global $wpdp;
            $dp = $wpdp->prefix."test-enes";
            $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `test-enes`");
            print_r ($result);
Output is:Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [key] => 1 [ingredients] => ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [key] => 2 [ingredients] => ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [key] => 3 [ingredients] => enes ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [key] => 4 [ingredients] => enes ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [key] => 5 [ingredients] => reer ) )
```

How can I pull the last element of the ingredients row.([ingredients] => reer) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$wpdp->prefix."test-enes ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Note: the **id** could be primary key of the table, you can put relevant primary key name